# How to access JPQL query return value (List)

Tags: jpa

This is my method

```
    public void makeDeposit(String WristID, double deposit) {

        List resultList = em.createQuery(
                "SELECT c FROM Tbleaccountcb005916 c WHERE c.wristid LIKE :wId")
                .setParameter("wId", WristID)
                .setMaxResults(1)
                .getResultList();

        int aNo = (int) resultList.get(0);

        Tbleaccountcb005916 makeDeposit = em.find(Tbleaccountcb005916.class, aNo);
        double balance = makeDeposit.getBalance();
        double Mdeposit = balance + deposit;

        makeDeposit.setBalance(Mdeposit);
        em.persist(makeDeposit);
    }
```

I would like to access resultList value. This image show the resultList values (debugged)

[image]

I need to access resultList value (accountno = value = 2) and use it.

I tried this but it's not working:

```
 int aNo = (int) resultList.get(0);
```

Comment: what error is spited?

Comment: aNo doesn't get value 2 @eduyayo

Comment: change query to `SELECT c.value FROM Tbleaccountcb005916 c WHERE c.wristid LIKE :wId` instead to return the value

Comment: Thank you sir @SamuelKok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks to @Samuel Kok I found an answer for this. I just change the query to "c.accountno"**

```js
 @Override
    public void makeDeposit(String WristID, double deposit) {

        List resultList;
        resultList = em.createQuery(
                "SELECT c.accountno FROM Tbleaccountcb005916 c WHERE c.wristid LIKE :wId")
                .setParameter("wId", WristID)
                .setMaxResults(1)
                .getResultList();

        int aNo = (int) resultList.get(0);

        Tbleaccountcb005916 makeDeposit = em.find(Tbleaccountcb005916.class, aNo);
        double balance = makeDeposit.getBalance();
        double Mdeposit = balance + deposit;

        makeDeposit.setBalance(Mdeposit);
        em.persist(makeDeposit);
    }
```

**Screen Shot of debugger** 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUE92.png)

Answer (score 1):

The query you've used returns a list of `Tbleaccountcb005916` since you're returning `c`in the query statement.

```
List resultList = em.createQuery(
  "SELECT c FROM Tbleaccountcb005916 c WHERE c.wristid LIKE :wId")
.setParameter("wId", WristID)
.setMaxResults(1)
.getResultList();
```

You can return `c.accountno` instead or cast the `resultList` items to `Tbleaccountcb005916`and access it's value.

Comment: Thank you sir. I post an answer to this with your help.